# Cookie value changing per request in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails 3 app everything works fine. Cookie value still constant on every request. But when I migrated to rails 4 it started to refresh on every request. Were there any changes in cookie mechanism in rails 4? And what I should do?

Comment: the session cookie, or what?

Comment: The cookie value, that stored in key, which set in ```initializers/session_store.rb``` file